# Algorithm to handle positive rating if there is huge difference between the number of reviews

Tags: algorithm, percentage, percentile

We have two products P1 and P2. P1 has total 1000 number of reviews and p2 has 200 reviews.

Positive rating of P1 is 85% (85% users are saying it's a good product)
Positive rating of P2 is 90% (90% users are saying it's a good product)

Now if we see technically P1 is better than P2 because 850 users are saying it's a good product while only 180 users are saying P2 is good.

How to solve this problem so that we can show a fair result? if possible please share the logic or algorithm.

Comment: This isn't a technical question. It is a business logic decision that needs to be made. You could equally argue that P1 is *worse* than P2 because 150 people are saying its not a good product whereas only 20 are saying that P2 is not good. The whole point of taking averages is that you can compare them. Personally I'd say a 90% average approval is better than an 85% average approval. If the 90% was only from one user then I may worry about its significance but once you get to reasonable numbers you can pretty much rely on the averages.

Comment: If you really want to worry about balancing for number of reviewers then you will probably want to go and ask on one of the other stack sites that deals with stats where they can talk about sample sizes and such things in much more detail. The following stacks sites may be able to help though I am not an active user on any of them so I can't say whether this is any more on topic there than here: https://stats.stackexchange.com, https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/confidence-interval-for-bernoulli-sampling

Comment: Chris is right. It's a model-decision and there is no answer for all cases. Often bayesian-approaches are used to incorporate a-priori information (e.g. imdb-scores).

Comment: A very simpe approach would be to multiply the average by log1000(positive votes). So values below 1000 positive votes become small because they are inaccurate and for a million votes the average is doubled.

Comment: You haven't been clear on your goal: what does it mean to "handle" these ratings?  If your purpose is to come up with a recommendation, then I suggest a one-tailed t-test to check whether P2 is better than P1 with your desired confidence level.  If you have some other purpose, please clarify.  Either way, I've voted to close this with a recommended move to the stats group.

Comment: Actually, we are saying P1 has 85% positive votes and P2 has 90% positive votes so when the user would see this he would like to prefer P2 but P1 is better than P2. Here I am tiring to simplify it so that P1 can be highlighted.

Comment: By boosting p1 or giving a score ... but not able to figure it out ...pls help if you understood the motive here.

Answer (score 1):

Check out confidence intervals on wikipedia ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval)).

Basically you would compute with 95% accuracy (or what level you want) that the actual value is between +/- x of the average you have. It depends on the number of data points so more reviews will give you a tighter interval.

What you do with it it's up to you. You can be pessimistic and show the lower end of the interval while being 95%+ sure that it's better than that.

If you want to compare the two you can look at the overlap between the intervals and conclude that they are about the same if the overlap is high.

Since this thing comes from statistics the guarantees assume some properties of the distribution, i.e. that P1 and P2 are judged similarly in this case. While not always true the confidence intervals tend to be useful.